# ROS_CANopen can't start velocity_controller and trajectory_controller

Tags: ros, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am working with ros_canopen to control a robot arm. The arm uses [Copley drives](http://www.copleycontrols.com/Motion/pdf/CANopenProgrammersManual.pdf). Please check out the github repo that I'm working on [here](https://github.com/Linkeway/BIRL_modular_robot).

1. The position controller (point to point move) works fine now. A littile problem here is I don't know how to specify the speed during the point-to-point move.
2. When I tried to start the `velocity_controller`:

   ```
   rosrun controller_manager controller_manager start I_Joint_velocity_controller
   ```

   errors would show up:

   ```
   [ERROR]: I_Jointcould not enter mode 2
   [ERROR]: Could not switch one joint for I_Joint_velocity_controller, will stop all related joints and the controller.
   [ERROR]: I_Joint is not ready to switch mode
   [ERROR]: Could not switch controllers. The hardware interface combination for the requested controllers is unfeasible.
   ```

   and if I start the `trajectory_controller`:

   ```
   rosrun controller_manager controller_manager start joint_trajectory_controller
   ```

errors would be:

```
    abort60c1#1, reason: Invalid value for parameter (download only).
    Could not process message

    [ERROR]: RPDO timeout; RPDO timeout;ros_canopen/canopen_master/src/sdo.cpp(429): Throw in function void canopen::SDOClient::transmitAndWait(const canopen::ObjectDict::Entry&, const canopen::String&, canopen::String*)
    Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<canopen::TimeoutException> >
    std::exception::what: SDO
    [canopen::tag_objectdict_key*] = 60c1sub1
```

Are these problems caused by wrong configuration of [my dcf file](https://github.com/Linkeway/BIRL_modular_robot/blob/master/birl_module_canopen/config/birl_copley.dcf)? I mapped the PDOs according to the [Copley programming manual](http://www.copleycontrols.com/Motion/pdf/CANopenProgrammersManual.pdf) p. 25

Many thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246705/ros_canopen-can%27t-start-velocity_controller-and-trajectory_controller/) by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2016-10-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-29**:
Just a tip (I always get confused as well): Askbot does not support github flavoured markdown. Use four spaces to start a code block, not three backticks.

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-10-29**:
Thanks. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> A littile problem here is I don't know how to specify the speed during the point-to-point move.

`canopen_motor_node`does not support setting the velocity dynamically (for this mode).
You can set it at start-up to a fixed value (Object 0x6081, the drive even supports more options).
I have opened a new issue for dynamic setting: https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/194

> I_Joint could not enter mode 2

According to the manual the drive just supports mode 3 (profiled velocity).
You should not have copied the Schunk DCF, the Copley drive seems to be more like the Elmo..

> and if I start the trajectory_controller:

The error message suggests that you should check the sent command.
Perhaps the drive have to be configured in a different way.
Please map 60c1sub1 to a PDO, otherwise IP mode will not work as expected.
(http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_402)

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2016-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-10-29**:
Hi Mathias. Thank you for your help.

I set the 6081 in dcf_overlay, as you've suggested, and used   `cansend can0 601#23.81.60.00.01.2c.08.00` to change the velocity of the motor after initialization.

It would nicer that the position_controller support speed adjustment after strart-up.

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-10-30**:
I mapped 60c1sub1 to RPDO2 with

```
dcf_overlay:
     "1601sub2": "0x60c10120"
```

It produced the same error when I called the canopen_motor init service. And candump stopped at :

```
can0  TX - -  601    40 C1 60 01 00 00 00 00
can0  RX - -  581    80 C1 60 01 01 00 01 06 # obj write only
```

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-10-31**:
(This is not the same error!)
Not sure what's going on here. It should be RW.
You can get rid o the read if you set a default value for 60c1sub1 in your DCF.